# AX=0 and introducing error matrix

Tags: matlab

I'm having a matrix of 10 rows and 5 columns, thatr I have called A
I would like to make AX=0 and determine X which contains 5 unknown parameters.

What I did is

```
null(A)
```

But it seems that it's considering what I did as a linear algebra.

I would like to introduce another matrix which contains a matrix of errors . which would give me a priori:
AX + E = 0
because the results are not accurate, indeed, but still, I would like to find the closest parameters of the unknown vector (X) and get an error matrix.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: You would like to _what_?

Comment: @Eitan Solve the equation AX=0 and have also an error matrix E

Comment: Whatever `A` is, if `A*X = 0` can't `X` (and `E`) just be `0`?

Comment: It can't. because, i'm dealing with  Overdetermined Systems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do eigen value decomposition of A^T.

```
[Q, D] = eigen(A^T)
```

And take the eigen vectors that corresponds to the smallest eigen value.
That is take y vectors from the right hand side of the Q matrix. 
y is the column number of X.

And then E = -AX

====edit=====

OK. actually you want to minimize E. But since E is a matrix I assume you want to minimize the sum of squares of all the elements in E.

That is:

```
||E||_F^2 = ||-AX||_F^2 = trace(X^T(A^TA)X)
```

You can do eigen decomposition of A^TA

```
[Q, D] = eigen(A^TA)

QA^TA = DQ    =>   D =  QA^TAQ^T
```

To make it smaller, X should be the columns of Qs that corresponds to the smallest eigen value in the diagonal of D.

If there is a eigen value equals to 0, then AX can be 0 and E=0

Comment: Actually what is T  ??

Comment: And my matrix is not square as mentioned before!

Comment: @MelMed I've modified the answer